# I want to get the content(NSString) whenever TextField content change

Tags: iphone, textfield

```
- ( BOOL ) textField: ( UITextField * )textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: ( NSRange )range replacementString: ( NSString * )string {

NSString *strCurrent;
if ( range.length > 0 ) {   // deleting
    int iNumberOfDeletedCharacter = [ string length ];
    int iNumberOfRestCharacter = [ [ textField text ] length ] - iNumberOfDeletedCharacter;
    strCurrent = [ [ textField text ] substringToIndex: iNumberOfRestCharacter - 1 ];
}
else {  // adding
    strCurrent = [ [ textField text ] stringByAppendingString: string ];
}

MyNSLog( @"%@", strCurrent );
```

}

This code has a problem in deleting part when characters of 2byte languages are entering.
Do you know easy ways for this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The posted code does some funny (broken) calculations on the text but its sense is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. If you want to calculate the resulting string after the edit:

```
NSString *editedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```